# Back to Back and Ladder Protection Diodes

Tags: diodes, capacitance, protection

I'm considering replicating this schematic from a paper (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5062317).  The idea of the circuit is to measure the capacitance of a transistor between the Drain and the Source at different Drain voltages (Vds).  But the trick is to not inject the high Vds voltages or currents into the sensitive impedance analyzer. C1 and C2 help keep DC current and voltage out of Hcur and Hpot while L1 shorts DC current away from Lcur and Lpot.

[image: Transistor Capacitance Measurement Circuit]

However, I'm not entirely sure what the different sets of protection diodes are suppose to accomplish.  Here is my understanding so far:

1. ZD1/ZD2 - clamps Hcur to +-10V
2. D1/ZD4/ZD3/D2 - the zeners clamp Hpot to +-10V but not sure what the 1N4004 diodes do
3. D3/D4 - diodes to ensure there is no voltage difference between C1 and C2 if one changes suddenly
4. Ladder of Diodes connected to Lcur and Lpot - no idea what this layout is used for

Could someone explain the point of each of these protection diodes layouts?

Comment: Are you sure of the circuit? Shorted diodes  D3, D4. D5 and D6 cannot do anything except exist and take room.

Comment: @user, those clip one diode drop. not uncommon

Comment: True, no doubt! But Maybe you have different image in front of you. On my screen there's wire between the ends of  D3, D4, D5 and D6.

Comment: @TrapLevel -- the diode ladder clips Lpot to within about 3 diode drops of ground...

Comment: @user , one would assume a long wire

Comment: Then that wire should have some spec. It cannot be given if there's no difference against other wires, even one letter symbol. 1N4004 isn't especially famous as a fast recovery diode in high speed pulse circuits.

Comment: yep, I'm also kindof wondering why they used ordinary silicon diodes instead of schottky's. It's from a scientific paper tho, maybe this is the "tried and true" method

Comment: also surprised that after all this effort, there isn't a Vgs protection, but maybe that would interfere with the measurement

Comment: My theory:   The 1N4004 are 200V blocking diodes.  i.e they can resist up to 200V reverse bias without breakdown.  So HPot must be able to get to a much higher voltage than HCur.    (Why D1/D2 is used)     Similarly, the network of D7/D12 must be able to swing close to +-600V (Maybe due to some excitement of the inductor?)   So they need that many diodes to ensure no reverse-breakdown occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drain-current AC voltage, induced by a current through Hcur-Lcur network branch, is measured by a [four-terminal-sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing)-enabled instrumentation. Anti-parallel diodes D3/D4 (D5/D6) limit voltage swing between Hcur/Hpot (Lcur/Lpot) which may happen in transient regimes and damage your measurement instrumentation. In a normal operation mode of voltage measurement, voltage drop across Hcur/Hpot (bzw. Lcur/Lpot) is small and well below a "knee" voltage of diodes D3/D4; the current terminal Hcur is well isolated from the voltage terminal Hpot of a [4-wire (Kelvin) clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing) at the high potential probe side; D5 and D6, also almost non-biased, isolate current (Lcur) and voltage (Lpot) terminals of a 4-wire clip at the low potential probe side.

In a 4-wire clip, Hpot is a voltage measurement terminal. The voltage protection network (clamp) is a shunt; when doing precise voltage measurement, the shunt resistance must be held as high as possible. D1(D2) blocks ZD4(ZD3) in the forward direction so that the impedance of the voltage protection network D1/ZD4/ZD3/D2 is high in the enabled voltage region. "Ladder of Diodes" (D7-D12) acts as a low-voltage (~2V) Zener diode.